# What separates 'conversation' questions from 'dialogue'?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have just edited the [tag wiki](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/dialogue/info) for [dialogue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) and have found in the 'related tags' section the tag [conversation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation).

[dialogue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) is about

> Questions about conversations between two or more people as a feature of a book, play, or film.

and [conversation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation) is

> For questions related to conversation or speech

What separates the two tags?
Should they be merged?

Comment: *Conversation* is unscripted. *Dialogue* is a scripted interaction which is designed to look like conversation. Subtle difference, maybe; but there is a difference.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Is there not some appropriate hypernym then? At the moment neither tag has very many uses and so it might be worth fusing them.

Comment: You can't do hypernyms with tags, only synonyms. And these two tags are definitely different.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I see your point, could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right the two tags are related — as indeed the system shows.

- *Conversation* is an unscripted interaction between two or more persons.
- *Dialogue,* as "a feature of a book, play or film," is a scripted interaction designed to look like a conversation.

The two tags are not synonyms: the scripted nature of one which is absent in the other is an important difference. *Conversation* is off-the-cuff, unconsciously spoken, while *dialogue* has had a third party consider it carefully in order that it **appears** to be instinctive. In reality, it's anything but.

Thus the *dialogue* of spoken conversation in JK Rowling's *Harry Potter* books, for example (about which we have had a number of questions) is not the same as *conversation* which real children have in the schoolyard<sup>1</sup>.

Nor is there a hypernym available. The tagging system doesn't handle hierarchies; it's only able to make equivalences at the same level. If we invented a hypernym like [spoken-interaction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-interaction) and then linked both [conversation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation) and [dialogue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialogue) to it, all three would become synonyms. The synonym system is designed to help with common misspellings like *dialog* for *dialogue*, or with alternative terms like *spelling* and *orthography.*

---

<sup>1</sup> Sorry, Harry Potter isn't real. Perhaps that should have been in spoiler markup.

Comment: Can you expand on how the scriptedness is an important distinction?  I'm not sure I see anything of significance in it.

Comment: @H Trying to explain subtle differences isn't always straightforward. Perhaps the current revision will do?

Comment: Much better, thanks. :-)

Comment: What do you mean Harry Potter isn't real?

Comment: Actually, there is technically only one party dictating all of the dialogue in most written stories: The other two are just figments of that first party's imagination. This is probably the most important distinction, as dialogue can be quite unnatural if the sole party considering it, did not consider [English As She Is Spoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke) adequately. Less importantly, with some reluctance, I should add that [dialog](http://www.tfd.com/dialog) is arguably a variation spelling of dialogue, like donut is to doughnut, rather than an outright misspelling.